# How to use Material Design Icons in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, material-design, bower, angular-material

I am using angular material design for giving responsive design to my AngularJS app. I am using material design icons which I install using:

```
bower install material-design-icons
```

Then I declare the css as CDN link which is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

I am using the icons by:

```
<i class="material-icons md-36 md-dark">person</i>
```

My problem is that there is no way to include css from bower_components. I want to replace CDN source to css with local source from bower_components. But I don't see any css file downloaded in my bower_components.

This is how my bower_components/material-design-icons directory look like:
[image]

I followed instructions given in [Material icons guide](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/), but couldn't figure out about including CSS from `bower_components`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `materil-design-icons` folder you have the `iconfont` folder, which contains your required CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of material design icons .... font icons and svg icons

The markup you have shown is for font icons

The bower package for the icon fonts is `material-design-iconfont`

Try `bower install material-design-iconfont ---save`

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question, you're trying to use material design on your web app. the package material-design-icons is just the icons [info](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons#material-design-icons).
I believe that, to achieve what you're looking for, you should get the bower google package [material design lite](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite) [info](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite#material-design-lite), they also provide a set of [templates](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite#templates)

There's also a [bootstrap material design](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design).